# Find the maximum likelihood estimate of...

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, maximum-likelihood

Suppose you have $n$ i.i.d random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ that are normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Thus,

$$ f_{X_i} (\mu , \sigma^2) = \left( \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \right) e^{\frac{-(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$

Find the likelihood function of the joint density and the maximum likelihood estimate for $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

I found the Likelihood function to be

$$ L(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \right)^n e^{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$

Taking the natural log of both sides then yielded

$$ \ln{L(x)} = \sum_{i=1}^n (-n\ln{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} - \frac{\sum(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\ln{L(x)} = \sum \sum (x_i - \mu) = 0 $$

Ideally, we are supposed to show that $\mu = \frac{\sum x_i}{n} $

Can someone help me see where I went wrong?

Comment: Why does your Likelihood function $L(x)$ have a $\prod$ and a $\sum$ rather than just one of them?  Similarly in logs, why two $\sum$s rather than one?

Comment: $\sum\limits_1^n (x_i - \mu) = 0$ can be rearranged to give $\mu = \frac{\sum x_i}{n}$

Comment: @Henry, the $f_{x_i} (\mu, \sigma^2) $ function i gave is the marginal density for each of the independent random variables $X_1, ... , X_n$. The joint density, since they are independent, is $\prod f_{x_i}$. 

In the problem, i'm supposed to find the maximum likelihood estimate for the joint density.

Comment: @math_noob I've deleted my answer, since I've regarded an univariate distribution only. Nevertheless I think you should work with two indices. One for the i-th distribution and one for the j-th sample: $x_{ij}, \sigma_i, \mu_i,...$

Comment: The joint density is $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \right) e^{\frac{- (x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}= \left( \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \right)^n e^{\frac{-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ as said in @callculus42's deleted answer, and the likelihood proportional to that.  This makes the log-likelihood $-n\ln(\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}) - \frac{\sum(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$ up to an additive constant

Answer (score 1):

$\log f = c - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$ so $\frac{d}{d\mu} \log f = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma^2}$ and $\frac{d}{d\mu} \log L \propto \sum x_i-\mu = 0.$
This gives $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n}\sum x_i$.

<sub>The joint density of independent variables is their product so the log likelihood is $\log L = \log \prod f(x_i) = \sum \log f(x_i)$. It is fine to maximize log instead of likelihood since $f$ is strictly increasing.</sub>